# Issue with multiple -exec statements for find command under ssh

Tags: ssh

I put together a find command that will find all java installs on a system.  It has 3 -exec clauses in it:
    find / -name java -type f -exec ls -l {} \; -exec {} -version \; -exec echo \;

When run from a command prompt, it generates output such as:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47308 Oct 11  2009 ./usr/java/jre1.6.0_17/bin/java
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47308 Nov 14 06:27 ./usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

The problem I'm having is the java version is not generated when I run the command from ssh.

```
ssh -T -o $USER@$ip_addr  "find / -name java -type f -exec ls -l {} \; -exec {} -version \; -exec echo \;" 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47308 Oct 11  2009 ./usr/java/jre1.6.0_17/bin/java

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47308 Nov 14 06:27 ./usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java
```

The 1st -exec clause is executed (ls -l).  The 2nd -exec clause is not working (java -version).  The 3rd -exec clause is executed (echo).

The problem is with the ssh command.  This works fine from within a shell script.  I've tried escaping some of the fields, but couldn't find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
Scott

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
java -version
```

sends its output to stderr, rather than stdout.

You can redirect stderr to stdout by appending

```
2>&1
```

to the command.  e.g.

```
ssh -T -o $USER@$ip_addr  "find / -name java -type f -exec ls -l {} \; -exec {} -version \; -exec echo \; 2>&1"
```